# When uploading solidity code to the EVM, does it also upload supporting openzepplin contracts? If so, why does it upload "Library" type files?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

When uploading solidity code to the EVM through Truffle (or anything), does it also upload supporting openzepplin contracts? If so, why does it upload "Library" type files? I thought "Library" files only needed to be uploaded once and everyone can use them?
Thanks!

Comment: Just a clarification: there is "upload" to P2P network. Contract bytecoed is a part of the deployment transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by "uploading" you mean deploying the compiled bytecode of your contracts on the blockchain.

When you compile your contracts you get a set of files containing bytecode, one per contract/library. If you're using contracts from OpenZeppelin by inheriting from them, their bytecode does not have to get deployed separately because it's compiled into your own contract. OZ contracts are mostly `abstract`, which makes the compiler not produce separate bytecode files for them anyway.

When using libraries, you only have to deploy them if you call their public or external functions. Internal functions get compiled into your own contract just as internal calls to inherited contracts. If Truffle is deploying your libraries, you probably do perform some external library calls.